# Images don't show up in quiz results after start over button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm posting this question again as I have a new problem now with my quiz. When I first take the quiz it works fine, then I click on the start over button to start the quiz again and it works just as well until I get to the results page, where the text and start over button appear but the images do not! How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   // DOC READY

var totalQuestions = $('.questionarea').length;  // VARIABLES
var currentQuestion = 0;
var $progressbar = $("#progressbar");
var score = 0;  
var value = 0;
$questions = $('.questionarea');
$questions.hide();


$("#startover").on("click", function(){  // STARTOVER
   $(this).hide();
   $(".answers").hide();
   $("#images").hide();
   $("#score").hide();
   $(".btn-lg").show();
   score = 0;
   value = 0;
   currentQuestion = 0;
   $progressbar.val(value);
   $questions.hide();
 });          

$(document).on("click", ".btn-lg", function(){ // START BUTTON FADE OUT
  $(this).hide();
  $progressbar.show(200);
  $(".answers").show(200);
  $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
  });


$(document).on("click", '.answers input', function(){  // NEW QUESTIONS FADE IN + PROGRESS BAR
  $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(200, function () {
    currentQuestion ++;
    if (currentQuestion === totalQuestions){
      $("#results").fadeIn(200);
    }
    else {
      $questions.eq(currentQuestion).fadeIn(200);
    }
    value = value + 10;
    $progressbar.val(value);
   });
 });


function calcScore() {   // OPTIONS CHECKED

var house1 = document.getElementById('option1').checked;  
var house2 = document.getElementById('option8').checked;
var house3 = document.getElementById('option11').checked;
var house4 = document.getElementById('option16').checked;
var house5 = document.getElementById('option18').checked;
var house6 = document.getElementById('option23').checked;  
var house7 = document.getElementById('option27').checked;  
var house8 = document.getElementById('option32').checked;
var house9 = document.getElementById('option35').checked;  
var house10 = document.getElementById('option36').checked;  


var sher1 = document.getElementById('option2').checked;  
var sher2 = document.getElementById('option6').checked;
var sher3 = document.getElementById('option10').checked;
var sher4 = document.getElementById('option14').checked;
var sher5 = document.getElementById('option19').checked;  
var sher6 = document.getElementById('option24').checked;
var sher7 = document.getElementById('option26').checked;
var sher8 = document.getElementById('option29').checked;
var sher9 = document.getElementById('option33').checked;  
var sher10 = document.getElementById('option37').checked;  

var cas1 = document.getElementById('option3').checked;  
var cas2 = document.getElementById('option7').checked;
var cas3 = document.getElementById('option9').checked;
var cas4 = document.getElementById('option15').checked;
var cas5 = document.getElementById('option17').checked;
var cas6 = document.getElementById('option21').checked; 
var cas7 = document.getElementById('option28').checked;  
var cas8 = document.getElementById('option30').checked;  
var cas9 = document.getElementById('option33').checked;  
var cas10 = document.getElementById('option38').checked;  

var brbad1 = document.getElementById('option4').checked;  
var brbad2 = document.getElementById('option5').checked;
var brbad3 = document.getElementById('option12').checked;
var brbad4 = document.getElementById('option13').checked; 
var brbad5 = document.getElementById('option20').checked; 
var brbad6 = document.getElementById('option22').checked;   
var brbad7 = document.getElementById('option25').checked;   
var brbad8 = document.getElementById('option31').checked;   
var brbad9 = document.getElementById('option34').checked; 
var brbad10 = document.getElementById('option39').checked;   


if(house1 === true){  // SCORE CALCULATION
  score += 1;
}  
if(house2 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house3 === true){
  score += 1;
}  
if(house4 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house5 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house6 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house7 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house8 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house9 === true){
  score += 1;
}
if(house10 === true){
  score += 1;
}  
if(sher1 === true){
  score += 2;
}  
if(sher2 === true){
  score += 2;
}
if(sher3 === true){
  score += 2;
}  
if(sher4 === true){
  score += 2;
}
if(sher5 === true){
  score += 2;
}  
if(sher6 === true){
  score += 2;
}
if(sher7 === true){
  score += 2;
}  
if(sher8 === true){
  score += 2;
}
if(sher9 === true){
  score += 2;
}
if(sher10 === true){
  score += 2;
}  
if(cas1 === true){
  score += 3;
}  
if(cas2 === true){
  score += 3;
}
if(cas3 === true){
  score += 3;
}  
if(cas4 === true){
  score += 3;
}
if(cas5 === true){
  score += 3;
}  
if(cas6 === true){
  score += 3;
}
if(cas7 === true){
  score += 3;
}  
if(cas8 === true){
  score += 3;
}
if(cas9 === true){
  score += 3;
}  
if(cas10 === true){
  score += 3;
}
if(brbad1 === true){
  score += 4;
}  
if(brbad2 === true){
  score += 4;
}
if(brbad3 === true){
  score += 4;
}  
if(brbad4 === true){
  score += 4;
  }
if(brbad5 === true){
  score += 4;
}  
if(brbad6 === true){
  score += 4;
}
if(brbad7 === true){
  score += 4;
}  
if(brbad8 === true){
  score += 4;
  }
if(brbad9 === true){
  score += 4;
}  
if(brbad10 === true){
  score += 4;
  } 

  // CHARACTER SCORE
if(score < 12){
  score = "House & Wilson!";
  $("#houseimage").show();
}  

if(score <= 20){   
  score = "Sherlock & John!";
  $("#sherimage").show();
}
if(score <= 30){
  score = "Dean & Cas!";
  $("#casimage").show();
}
if(score <= 40){
  score = "Walt & Jesse!";
  $("#brbadimage").show();
 }

} 

  // SHOW RESULTS

$("#results").click(function(){ 
  $(this).hide();
  $progressbar.hide();
  $("#startover").show();
  calcScore();
  $("#score").show();
  document.getElementById("score").innerText = 'You Got: ' + score; 
   }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container box">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="text-center" id="title"> WHICH TV BROMANCE ARE YOU AND YOUR BFF? </div></div> 

  <div class="col-sm-11 text-center divprogress">
    <div class="text-center">
      <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-animated center-block" style="width: 0%, text-align: center" id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress> </div></div>
<br>
<br>

  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg text-center" id="start">START QUIZ</button></div>

<!-- QUIZ AREA -->

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 1 -->
<div id="content">  
  <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA1" data-question"1">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question1">Q1: How did you and your BFF meet?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="option1"> At work </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" id="option2"> Living together</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3" id="option3"> Under unusual or other circumstances</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="4" id="option4"> In school</label></div></div>
  </div>  

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 2 -->  
  <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA2" data-question"2">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question2">Q2: How long have you known each other?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
    <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="4" id="option5"> Less than 3 years </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" id="option6"> 4-7 years</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3" id="option7"> At least 8 years</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" id="option8"> Over 20 years</label></div></div>

</div>  


<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 3 -->  
  <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA3" data-question"3">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question3">Q3: How would you describe your friendship?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
    <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3" id="option9"> Deep </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" id="option10"> Amazing</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="option11"> Needy</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="4" id="option12"> Protective</label></div></div>

</div>

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 4 -->  
  <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA4" data-question"3">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question4">Q4: What do you do together?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="4" id="option13"> Business </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2" id="option14"> Go out</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3" id="option15"> Just hold each other</label>         </div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1" id="option16"> Play pranks on each other</label></div></div>  

    </div>

 <!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 5 -->        
   <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA5" data-question"4">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question5">Q5: How often do you fight?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3" id="option17"> Not much, but when we do, it's a big deal </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1" id="option18"> We have lots of harmless tiffs</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2" id="option19"> Sometimes</label>         </div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="4" id="option20"> Often and it can get physical</label></div></div>    
 </div>
  <!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 6 -->        
   <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA6" data-question"4">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question6">Q6: How well do you know each other?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3" id="option21"> Quite a lot </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="4" id="option22"> Not much</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1" id="option23"> We know every detail of each other's lives</label>         </div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" id="option24"> He knows way more about my life than I know about his (or viceversa)</label></div></div>    

  </div>

 <!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 7 -->        
   <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA7" data-question"4">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question7">Q7: Do you celebrate your birthdays together?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="4" id="option25"> No, but I buy him a great present </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2" id="option26"> Of course</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1" id="option27"> Often</label>         </div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3" id="option28"> Only if he's in town at the time</label></div></div>    

  </div>   

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 8 -->        
   <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA8" data-question"4">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question8">Q8: How often are you around each other's houses?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="2" id="option29"> We live together </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="3" id="option30"> Often</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question8" value="4" id="option31"> Not often</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="1" id="option32"> All the time</label></div></div>    

  </div>     

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 9 -->        
   <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA9" data-question"4">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question9">Q9: How often do you talk about your feelings?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="3" id="option33"> No need. We can see right through each other </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="2" id="option33"> Occasionally</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question9" value="4" id="option34"> Rarely</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="1" id="option35"> Only in a joking manner</label></div></div>    

  </div>      

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 10 -->        
   <div class="questionarea text-center" id="QA10" data-question"4">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question10">Q10: What do you consider each other as?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="1" id="option36"> Life partners </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="2" id="option37"> Best friends</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="question10" value="3" id="option38"> Family (brothers)</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="4" id="option39"> Family (father/son)</label></div></div>    

  </div>  


<!-- ---- -->   
<button id="results">View Results</button>
<h2 id='score'></h2>  

<div id="images">
<img id="houseimage" src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m70pdclcae1qcy01ao1_500.gif" />
<img id="brbadimage" 

src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/c88e253d9ed37f2cf422bf4bef27bcbc/tumblr_n52r45b3YW1qglx18o1_r1_250.gif" />
<img id="sherimage" src="http://read.html5.qq.com/image?src=forum&q=5&r=0&imgflag=7&imageUrl=http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz/4vhrz0icYkiaUHCPsiaJUKMEsFnUWwluggISyy0iaAaZvhOxcKhdc3XLK8LhSc3q52lOaIvBzsuZP93STzKEyqoYBw/0?wx_fmt=gif" />
<img id="casimage" src="http://66.media.tumblr.com/9c0723fa2ff4054cea2d0a530802fef8/tumblr_inline_mtnsncH2fn1qjt6x6.gif" />
</div>

  <div><button id="startover">Start Over</button></div>   

  </div>

  </div>   
</body>
```

CSS:

```
// HEADER AND BOX

body {
  background-image: url("http://wallpoper.com/images/00/40/76/15/gregory-house_00407615.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: fixed;
}
.header {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#title {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
.box {
  width: 900px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #ba348b;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 4px black;
  padding: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: none;
}


// START QUIZ BUTTON
#start {
  background-color: #00c6d2;
  border: 2px solid #13281c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #13281c;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 110px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  &:hover {
    background-color: 
#009ea8;
  }
}
.btn-lg {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

// PROGRESS BAR

.divprogress {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#progressbar {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 780px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}

// QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS

#QA1, #QA2, #QA3, #QA4, #QA5, #QA6, #QA7, #QA8, #QA9, #QA10 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  color: #13281c;
  display: none;
}
.questionarea {
  display: none;
}
.col-lg-6 {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.question1, .question2, .question3, .question4, .question5, .question6, .question7, .question8, .question9, .question10 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn-primary {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffff32 !important;
  color: #13281c !important;
  outline: 0 none;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 0 none;
  &:hover{
    background-color: #e5e500 !important;
    color: black !important;
    outline: 0 none;
  }
}

// RESULTS BUTTON / TEXT

#results {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #609D57;
  border: 3px solid darkgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  float: center;
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #13281c !important;
  outline: 0 none;
  opacity: 1;
  &:hover{
    background-color: #568d4e !important;
    color: black !important;
    outline: 0 none;
  }
}

#score {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  float: center;
  color: #920602;
}

#startover{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: fantasy, serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: center;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(211,211,211, 0.7);
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(211,211,211, 1);
  }
}

// IMAGES

#houseimage, #sherimage, #casimage, #brbadimage {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#houseimage, #sherimage, #brbadimage {
  height: 240px;
}
```

Comment: With so much code, a Fiddle or CodePen would be nice to replicate your problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about that! gonna post it on fiddle soon but I wanted it to at least be working before I show it to the world lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the `startOver` function is hiding all the images.

```
$("#images").hide();
```

You need to hide the individual image tags instead of the div with `$('#images img')`

I added this helper to your code:

```
function hideImages() {
  $('#images img').hide();
}

hideImages();
```

See the demo here: https://jsbin.com/bezimupihi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your help! However depending on the results now two images appear at the same time, when only 1 image should appear (according to the results you got). I don't know why your code seems to be working fine and mine doesn't! Can it be because of CSS as I have not posted it? Gonna edit my OP to include it just in case... otherwise I don't know what the problem is!

Comment: @Evan I am not sure what you mean. I didn't change your javascript much. See this new version: https://jsbin.com/lubikoweze/1/edit?js,output